# stubbing controllers in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying to fathom controller testing, and with that, mocking and stubbing. I think I get the latter, however, not being so confident in my tests I am unwilling to place any faith in the current failing test I am about to explain.

```
RSpec.describe CorporateContactFormsController, :type => :controller do
    let!(:contact_form){ FactoryGirl.create :corporate_contact_form }
    let!(:params_new){ {corporate_contact_form: {}} }

  describe "POST create" do
    before do 
        CorporateContactForm.stub(:new).and_return(contact_form)
      get :new, params_new
    end

    it "returns http success" do
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
  describe "POST create" do
    before do
        CorporateContactForm.stub(:new).and_return(contact_form)
    end
    describe "where all is good" do
      before do
        contact_form.stub(:save).and_return(true)
        post 'create', params_new
      end
      it "should set a flash notice" do
        flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
      end
      it "should redirect to edit_details page" do
        response.should redirect_to employees_path
      end
    end
  end

end
```

So here I am testing the controller which deals with form submissions. But here is where I am lost...

```
  def create
    if corporate_contact_form_params.present?
      @contact_form = CorporateContactForm.new(corporate_contact_form_params)
      if @contact_form.save
        if @contact_form.contact_type == CorporateContactForm::EMPLOYEE 
          redirect_to employees_path
        else
          redirect_to employers_path
        end
        flash[:notice] = 'Form submitted'
        return
      end
    end
    render new
  end

  private 

  def corporate_contact_form_params
    params.require(:corporate_contact_form).permit(:firstname, :surname, :contact_number, :email, :company_name, :method_of_payment, :number_of_employees, :comments, :contact_type)
  end
```

With my parameters set as above, I get the failing test

```
Failure/Error: post 'create', params_new
     ActionController::ParameterMissing:
       param is missing or the value is empty: corporate_contact_form
```

I really am struggling to understand what's going on here, why should this test fail, because its works in development. Why would the first `describe "POST create` test pass and not the next block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear: `param is missing or the value is empty: corporate_contact_form`. The value you are passing under `corporate_contact_form` key is empty and `require` is not happy about that. Try changing your `let!` (should be `let`, eager load is obsolete in this case) to sth like:

```
let!(:params_new){ {corporate_contact_form: { firstname: ''} } }
```

EDIT:

This is how `require` method is defined:

```
def require(key)
  value = self[key]
  if value.present? || value == false
    value
  else
    raise ParameterMissing.new(key)
  end
end
```

`present` method returns false for empty hash.

Comment: That's brilliant, it worked. I am not sure why though, i thought by just giving empty curly braces I was indication blank parameters. why does that work?

Comment: @FredBenfield - explained. :)